# How to implement Spring-MVC CRUD operations on MongoDB without using MongoTemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc

I want to know how to develop a sample CRUD operations on MongoDB with MongoRepository Interface.

Can anyone give me the links which do not have MongoTemplate example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a sample application last year, using VRaptor + MongoDB + Spring Data but I think that it will be useful to you.

The github repository is https://github.com/cartagena/heroku-vraptor-mongodb.

If you take a looks at [vraptor's controller class](https://github.com/cartagena/heroku-vraptor-mongodb/blob/master/src/main/java/com/petrusti/herokusample/controller/ClientController.java), which is very similar to spring-mvc controller, you can see the repositry in action.